# Having problems with strpos in php

Tags: php, mysqli

I run a dog pedigree site and trying to show images based on whether dog is a champion.

Now you get different champions Italian, French etc.

The first line works but the second does not for the dog whose name begins with IT/CH?

```
<?php 
    if (strpos($dog_name, "CH", 0)=== false) 
        echo '<img src="img/first.png"></img>';
?>
```

This above works if the dog has just CH at the front of name as CH Dudley at Whereof

This one below does not work why?

```
<?php 
    if (strpos($dog_name, "IT/CH", 0)=== false) 
        echo '<img src="img/uk_champ.png"></img>';
?>
```

Dogs name is IT/CH Famersco Hadley.

I'm really stuck on this - any help would be useful.

Comment: You might want to just separate that from the `$dog_name`, it will be much easier in the long run, especially if the context of your site is about ranking.

Comment: yeah like have a row in mysql table for titles

Comment: Yeah, would make changing/amending the dogs name a lot less hassle, also you be able to filter without `LIKE "CH%"` shenanigans

Comment: Your first one is false as it is not starting with "CH" so the image gets printed. But the 2nd one is true as the dog_name starts with "IT/CH" so it is not false hence the image won't get printed. You should understand your own logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is working perfectly. In the 1st example it returns false as the $dog_name not starts with 0. But in the 2nd example it is not false as it is starting with "IT/CH"

If you want to see a match anywhere in the string just use strpos without the 3rd parameter

```
if (strpos($dog_name, "CH")=== false) 
echo '<img src="img/uk_champ.png"></img>';
```

and

```
if (strpos($dog_name, "IT/CH")=== false) 
echo '<img src="img/uk_champ.png"></img>';
```

Comment: I tested it without the 0 same behaviour, one would think it should return 0 but nope.  See the sandbox link in my answer.  It also has nothing to do with that particular string as it does the same thing with `foo`

Comment: Well with my example, you have both "CH" and "IT/CH" in your string. So strpos won't return false. If you are checking whether the substring exists in the string you should use if (strpos($dog_name, "IT/CH")!== false) . BTW, if you meant the same, you can use your original code by changing ===false to !==false. It will definitely work

Comment: Man I totally missed the `===` I updated my answer. lol good catch.

Comment: It's not my question, but you have the answer (or pointed the way), but your answer is not correct.  See my answer.